# Передача переменной из select в php, для сортировки в mysql

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Бьюсь над этой проблемой уже 3-ий день.

Имеется php код, который выводит данные из бд mysql, в частности таблицы members. Всё отлично выводит, а теперь мне необходимо отсортировать вывод по одному столбцу, а именно stage, в нем только два значения Очный и Заочный.
Как не пытался, никак не получается даже передать переменную из select в php.

Пример кода прикрепил

```html
<form action="player.php" method="POST">
                        <label for="stage">Сортировать по участию:</label>
                            <select name="stage" id="stage">
                                <option value='' disabled>Выберите этап</option>
                                <option value='Очный'>Очный</option>
                                <option value='Заочный'>Заочный</option>    
                            </select> 
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <button class="dws-submit2" value="Выбрать" type="submit" onclick="location.href='player.php'" name="stage">Выбрать</button><hr>
```

```
<?php
            include_once("bd.php");
            echo $s=$_POST['stage'];
            $query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY team");

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))

            {
                echo '<p>'.'Вариант участия: '.'<span>'.$row['stage'].'</span>'.'</p>';
                echo '<p>'.'Название команды: '.'<span>'.$row['team'].'</span>'.'</p>';
                echo '<p>'.'ФИО первого участника: '.'<span>'.$row['fio_mem1'].'</span>'.'</p>';
                echo '<p>'.'ФИО второго участника: '.'<span>'.$row['fio_mem2'].'</span>'.'</p>';
                echo '<p>'.'ФИО третьего участника: '.'<span>'.$row['fio_mem3'].'</span>'.'</p>';
                echo '<p>'.'Город: '.'<span>'.$row['city'].'</span>'.'</p>';
                echo '<p>'.'Учебное учреждение: '.'<span>'.$row['institution'].'</span>'.'</p>';
                echo '<p>'.'Класс\Специальность: '.'<span>'.$row['klass'].'</span>'.'</p>';
                echo '<p>'.'Телефон руководителя: '.'<span>'.$row['tel'].'</span>'.'</p>';
                echo '<p>'.'e-mail руководителя: '.'<span>'.$row['mail'].'</span>'.'</p>';
                echo '<p>'.'ФИО руководителя: '.'<span>'.$row['head'].'</span>'.'</p>';
                echo '<p>'.'Должность руководителя: '.'<span>'.$row['position'].'</span>'.'</p>';
                echo '<div class="sert"><a href="./sert/'.$row['sert'].'">'.'Дипломы участников'.'</a></div>'.'<hr>';
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: И в чем суть __сортировки__ по значению "Очный"?

Comment: это получается этапы участия, есть Очный этап, а есть Заочный, потому необходимо выводить участников только очного или заочного этапа

Comment: Тогда это не сортировка а __фильтрация__

Comment: ну да, согласен, неправильно выразился

Comment: `WHERE stage="Что-то"`

Comment: $query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY team"); 
этот запрос изменить?

Comment: Прочитать и разобраться как использовать в запросах условия `WHERE`.

Comment: include_once(db.php);
$zapros="SELECT * FROM members WHERE stage='".$_POST['stage']."'";
                

$result = $link->query($zapros) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));

                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
Пытался таким способом всё равно без успеха, вообще ничего не выводит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE название в БД = 'Очный' ORDER BY team ");

MySQL оператор WHERE используется для фильтрации результатов в операторах SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE или DELETE.

Так же:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
   <label for="stage">Сортировать по участию:</label>
   <select name="stage" id="stage">
      <option value='' disabled>Выберите этап</option>
      <option value='Очный'>Очный</option>
      <option value='Заочный'>Заочный</option>
   </select>
   <button class="dws-submit2" value="Выбрать" type="submit" name="stage">Выбрать</button>
</form>
</div>
<?
echo $_POST['stage'];
?>
```

Comment: да я понимаю это, у меня так тоже получалось, проблема-то в том, чтобы выполнить фильтрацию, по средством select в HTML, то есть я выбираю Заочный в select, и данные об этом выборе передаются в запрос в PHP

Comment: $query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE stage ='".$_POST['stage']."'");
Пытался такой запрос, также безрезультатно

Comment: $s = $_POST['stage'] попробуй так: WHERE `stage` = '$s'

Comment: include_once("bd.php");
                $s = $_POST['stage'];
                $query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE WHERE stage = '$s' ORDER BY team ");
                echo $s;
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
Даже просто переменную отказывается выводить, вся проблема в том, что он не хочет значение передавать из select, а почему не могу понять

Comment: Подправил ответ, проблема была в том, что кнопка не в тегах form, соответственно, не передавала данные

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень сильно помогли, я уже запросы переписывал столько раз, а оказалось ошибка в этом